# Unable to run code inside python unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm having an issue when trying to write unit tests for a python3 script. The code is throwing a AttributeError while running inside a test definition, but does not if I run the same code in the same file outside of the test definitions class.

The code:

```
class TestDataCleaningMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        data = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
            'categoryId',
            'regionId',
            'districtId',
            'jobType',
            'contractType',
            'payType'])
        result = service.__columns_to_snake_case(data)
```

Throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'service' has no attribute '_TestDataCleaningMethods__columns_to_snake_case'
```

I've had a search around, and found a few questions and answers regarding attribute errors on unittest, but haven't seen any that quite match this issue.

---

Another thing to note is that I've Monkey-patched `import` to return Mocks, but I can't see it interfering with the functioning of unittest. In the interest of completedness, this is that code:

```
orig_import = __import__

original_imports = [
    "service",
    "pandas"
]

def import_mock(name, *args):
    if name in original_imports:
        print(f"Using original imports for {name}")
        return orig_import(name, *args)
    print(f"Mocking {name}")
    return mock.MagicMock()


with mock.patch('builtins.__import__', side_effect=import_mock):
    import service
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, turns out it is an issue with double underscores in function names. Double underscore makes the python interpreter to rename the attribute to prevent conflicts. Changing the function names to remove the double underscore fixes the issue.